# regex python replace a line

Tags: python, regex

I need help to replace a line in an html file

line to replace:

```
        $url = 'www.youtube.com/watch?v=y6120QOlsfU';
```

The python script I am using(does not work):

```
with open(mywebpage, 'r+') as f:
     text = f.read ()
     text = re.sub("            $url = 'www.youtube.com.*","            $url ='www.youtube.com{};".format(newyoutubelink), text)
     f.seek(0)
     f.write(text)
```

Comment: What exactly is wrong with it? Does it raise an exception? If so, what exception? Does it give the wrong output? If so, what is it returning, and what did you expect? Is it giving no output?

Comment: Please elaborate on what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: @KSFT it is not changing the file and it does not raise an exeption

Comment: Try printing `text` before and after you assign it to the result of `re.sub()`. Is it changing? That should help isolate the problem.

Comment: @DarwinvonCorax i am trying to change the youtube link /watch...

Comment: @KSFT i tried that it is not changing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dollar signs and dots are a special characters in regular expressions. You need to escape them with a backslash. It also looks like the end of your regex isn't correct. You probably want something like this:

```
\$url = www\.youtube\.com/watch\?v=y6120QOlsfU'
```

Because you know what you're replacing, though, you can just use [`str.replace()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace):

```
text=text.replace("www.youtube.com/watch?v=y6120QOlsfU","$url ='www.youtube.com{};".format(newyoutubelink))
```